# При переходе с Apache на nginx возникла проблема с ЧПУ

Tags: php, nginx, apache

Проект разработан на php.
При попытке перехода с apache на nginx возникла проблема с ЧПУ.

В apache конфиг был следующий:

```
Options All -Indexes    
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Для nginx я использовал:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
```

Это спасло частично ситуацию.

При попадании на сайт "http://site.com/" и "http://site.com/../../" и тд путь в константе "__DIR__" указывается до директории где лежит основная часть логике, а когда http://site.com/admin/ в константе указывается путь до директории где лежит другая логика проекта admin.

Вся проблема в том что когда добавляется после "http://site.com/admin/" (http://site.com/admin/../../) ещё один сегмент url в константе получается путь до основной директории а не до admin.

Пример как должен выглядеть путь в константе: /var/www/test-app/admin/
В моём случае /var/www/test-app/

Я пытался разобраться как написать так чтобы всё работало но не получилось.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечу сам на свой вопрос.
Решения пришло следующие.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
            index index.php index.html index.htm;   
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    server_tokens off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location @phalcon {
            rewrite ^/admin/(.+)$ /admin/index.php?$args=$1 last;
    }

    location /admin/ {
            index index.php;
            if ($uri !~ ^/admin) {
                    rewrite ^/admin(.*)$ /admin$1;
            }
            try_files $uri $uri/ @phalcon;
    }

}
```

Nginx полностью настраивал я и данный конфиг находиться в /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.

То есть я просто добавил

```
location @phalcon {
        rewrite ^/admin/(.+)$ /admin/index.php?$args=$1 last;
}

location /admin/ {
        index index.php;
        if ($uri !~ ^/admin) {
                rewrite ^/admin(.*)$ /admin$1;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ @phalcon;
}
```

**Теперь следующий вопро можно ли упростить это или есть более простое решение?
Причина в том что кроме директории admin есть и другие.**

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в конфиг Nginx:

```
location ^~ /admin {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.php?$query_string;
}
```

А указанную в вопросе директиву try_files поместите в `location /`

Comment: Если я добавляю эти строки начинает загружать пустой файл по этому url("http://site.com/admin/../../").